# Dual-boot installed Ubuntu Touch, link Android userdata to /home/phablet, Google Chat and Calendar syncing

Tags: ubuntu-touch, sync, evolution, calendar, google-hangouts

I did [dual-boot installation of Ubuntu Touch 14.04 r302](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/DualBootInstallation) on my Nexus 4 and would like to make a link under the `/home/phablet/Pictures` directory to my pictures created with Android saved in `/userdata/media/0/DCIM` so that I can see them in the gallery. How can I do that?

Anyway, the problem is the following: if I copy some music to ~/aaa and issue

```
sudo mount --bind ~/aaa ~/Music/aaa
```

as phablet, the music is not seen by the music scope. Same is true for video scope and gallery app. Strangely, if I copy contents of ~/aaa to ~/Music/bbb, the music is recognized by music scopes. Can someone confirm this? Why is this?

Others questions for ubuntu touch:

-is there a way to use Google Chat/Hangouts on Ubuntu Touch? If yes, how (i can't find it neither in browser nor with gmail app)?

-Google calendar is synced but when I add an event on Ubuntu Touch it is not synchronised with Google server. How can I set sync settings: How often it syncs calendar and whether syncing is bidirectional or not?

Thanks for help in advance!

Comment: Use syncevolution to setup sync with google calendar (caldav).Link: http://is.gd/a59mG5.

Comment: What is the permission of `/userdata/media/0/DCIM ` folder? Don't create a symlink...instead just copy to userdata/DCIMandroid. Then try to change the permision as phablet user: `chmod -R 755 /home/userdata/DCIMandroid/`. Does this solve the problem?

Comment: Thanks for the syncevolution setup link. I really don't want to copy, linking would be better, because you don't double space requirements. Just that I can't edit /root/.bashrc now...see above